# Guava EventBus waiting for result

Tags: java, guava, event-bus

I am using guava EventBus to do event processing, and it's good. Now I need to get the result of one subscriber. I know the design of guava eventBus that I should not try to do that. But I need this for now  .

Can I do like this:
I create an event with a countdown lock.

```
Class SomeEvent {
    private String someData;
    private String someDataUsedForResult;
    private CountDownLatch countDown = new CountDownLatch(2);
    ...
}
```

Then in my subscriber, after the event is finished, update result filed in event, decrease the count down lock to 0. And in the place I post the event, I wait for the count down lock and get result.

Can I do it this way?

Comment: _Given_ that you're not supposed to do that, instead of doing the `CountDownLatch` shenanigans I would use a `SettableFuture` and wait for that to finish instead of trying to do this roundabout way.

Comment: Thanks, it's better, i can return result message and control return with one obj.